# WooCommerce compatibility - using get_id() method with older versions in third party plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, plugins, woocommerce

Does anyone know if it would be possible to add the `get_id()` method with an older version of WooCommerce in a third party plugin, so it would work with the Google tag manager plugin?

I don't want to update the plugin right now as it would mess up to site.

Anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the PHP function [**`method_exists()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) on any WooCommerce object like `WC_Product` or `WC_Order` objects...

Here is an example with `WC_Product` object **`$product`**:

```
// WooCommerce retro-compatibility (compact)
$product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $order->id;
```

Or you can use version_compare() PHP function too:

```
// WooCommerce retro-compatibility (2)
if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
    // Older than 3.0
    $product_id = $product->id;
} else {
    // 3.0 and above
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
}
```

and the same in a compact way:

```
$product_id = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $product->id : $product->get_id();
```

*(the **`$product`** is an existing and defined **`WC_Product`** object…)*

Comment: So this would work? `$product_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' );` instead of this? `$product_id = $product->get_id();` Product is already defined?

Comment: @ciaranpflanagan I have updated my answer with `$product` instead of `$order` … And yes the  `$product` is a defined and existing WC_Product object *(just like in older versions of WooCommerce)* … This answer allow to give to your code a version compatibility. So your code will work with WC 2.6.x and WC 3+ too

Comment: Just to clear up the comment above, the product var is already defined. Not sure why I added an ?.

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to clear up the first comment because I realised that asking if the product var was already defined when I knew it was might have been a bit confusing. Thanks, your answer works perfectly

Comment: Done, what would be the best way of adding a function called `get_id();` to the Woocommerce plugin using your code so that other plugins could access it. For example, I've a plugin that integrates using the `get_id();` function but I want to avoid editing the plugin in case I want to update it in the future?

Comment: @ciaranpflanagan In WooCommerce version 3+, `get_id()` is an inherited method from WC_data class mainly for WooCommerce Orders and Product objects (WC_Order, WC_Product…). It allows to get the related Object ID … So you can't redefine this method (or function). Read this related post: [Deprecation in WooCommerce Core](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2017/01/17/deprecation-in-woocommerce-core/) … retro compatibility will your code working with your older WooCommerce version and with most recent version too…

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this for code compatibility with old version

```
global $woocommerce;
// if old version of WooCommerce
$product_object = version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0', '<' ) ? 
$order_data->get_product_from_item( $item ) : $item->get_product();
```